# IO throughput lower when only a single process using the disk?

Tags: linux, centos, io

I am running a busy cacti server on centos and sometimes the `rrdtool` process is painfully slow when writing to disk, in HTOP the IO Column would display something between 100-300. 
I a polling cycle comes in `mysqld` can get up to 3000 IO and the `rrdtool` process also spikes to 1000 or 2000 then falls back when `mysqld` is done with its IO.

I don't know what the number represents but on other cactis the higher the number the quicker the process is finishing its disk use with the same amount of work to do. On another one the `rrdtool` would get up to 16 000 and it's going through a similar number of updates as this slow one, and it finishes orders of magnitude faster, on the same virtual host, same configuration.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? I've had the scheduler as noop and the nr_requests as 32 for a long while now. If I change the scheduler I don't see different behaviour and increasing the queue size is very quickly increasing latency and making it even slower. It's a virtual server but the disks themselves are local to the virtual host.

Comment: Same filesystem on those virtual discs? Same filesystem on the hosts?

Comment: The host is vmware or something, virtuals know nothing of the hardware, and yes ext3 on all of them CentOSes.